# Excel- how to find two different texts in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a very large excel document that we use to log construction projects.    we have multiple columns with different info:   I am trying to figure out a formula  to be able to search so i can find  a row that contains a specific address and floor (the address and the floor are in their own column) Currently we use the find tool searching the address and then have to go row by row to find the floor. Is there a formula or search where it will locate the specific row that contains the address and floor? 348 & 494 reference the row number in our excel.  Thank you in advance for any help.

```
                  F             H             I
               address     /  floor    /    city 

348           915 Wilshire /   14      /      LA

494           915 Wilshire /   20      /      LA
```

Comment: Have you considered using filters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT()` to do multiple criteria searching:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(F:F="915 Wilshire")*(G:G=14)*(H:H="LA")*ROW(1:1048576))
```

[image]

This finds the row number of the record for 915 Wilshire, 14th floor, city of LA.  The formula will work if only **one** row has the matching criteria.

If more than one row meets all criteria, then a helper column can locate all matching rows.

Comment: The formula worked, but it presented another problem.  If the address and floor is listed multiple times throughout the document it adds those rows together.  Is there a way to have it list each specific row separately?  Can the search be done so that it will return floors that are listed as 14 and as 1400

Comment: @ERU_MCP  My formula will return a single row number if a single row meets all criteria.................if multiple rows meet the criteria, then consider using *AutoFilter* to locate those rows.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add a column that concatenates the values in each row.  This way you'll have everything you want to search by in one column. (Maybe make the column narrow so it's not too much in the way.)

Put this in an empty column, and fill down onto all rows:

```
=F348&"-"&text(H348,"0")&"-"&I348              yields "915 Wilshire-14-LA"
```

Note, for fields that may be numeric, use `text()` to avoid any problem with concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution, as far as I understand your data set and needs, would be to use a Pivot Table, together with slicers. I see many advantages:

- It doesn't require any additional formula in your data table. Pivot tables are directly configurable in the ribbon, so it's fairly easy to set up and use(especially useful if people using the workbook are not too familiar with Excel)
- With a large data set, it won't slow up the workbook, unlike functions like `SUMPRODUCT`
- The [slicers](https://trumpexcel.com/slicers-excel-pivot-table/) are useful to quickly select data
- You can also use the flexibility of the Pivot Table to group and synthesize data. For instance, if you want to see or count all construction projects in a given city, or list all projects on the same address.
- You can create as many Pivot Tables as you want, to serve different needs.
- If you have dates in your data sets, you can take advantage of the timeline widget to filter results in a convenient way

---

### Useful documentation

- [Using Pivot Tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576)
- [How to use slicers](https://trumpexcel.com/slicers-excel-pivot-table/)
- [How to use timelines](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-pivottable-timeline-to-filter-dates-d3956083-01be-408c-906d-6fc99d9fadfa)